# How to disable heartbeats with pika and rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using rabbitmq to facilitate some tasks from my rabbit server to my respective consumers. I have noticed that when I run some rather lengthy tests, 20+ minutes, my consumer will lose contact with the producer after it completes it's task. In my rabbit logs, I have seen the error

```
closing AMQP connection <0.14009.27> (192.168.101.2:64855 -> 
192.168.101.3:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```

Also, I receive this error from pika

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: (-1, "error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')")
```

I'm assuming this is due to this code right here and the conflict of heartbeats with the lengthy blocking connection time.

```
 self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.101.2', 5672, 'user', credentials))
    self.channel = self.connection.channel()
    self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.tool,
                               arguments={'x-message-ttl': 1000,
                                             "x-dead-letter-exchange": "dlx",
                                             "x-dead-letter-routing-key": "dl",
                                             'durable': True})
```

Is there a proper way to increase the heartbeat time or how would I turn it off(would it be wise to) completely? Like I said, tests that are 20+ min seem to lead to a closedconnection error but I've ran plenty of tests from the 1-15 minute mark where everything is fine and the consumer client continues to wait for a message to be delivered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please don't disable heartbeats. Instead, use Pika correctly. This means:

- Use Pika version `0.12.0`
- Do your long-running task in a separate thread
- When your task completes, use the `add_callback_threadsafe` method to schedule the `basic_ack` call.

Example code can be found here: [link](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py)

I'm a RabbitMQ core team member and Pika maintainer.

Comment: This is actually the recommended way to go. Nevertheless IMHO this should be something provided by Pika. Pushing the users to go MT is not ideal. Especially considering now Pika has blocking connections.

Comment: I've been maintaining Pika since version `0.11.0` and, as far as I know, Pika has always required that the user not block the ioloop, even when using the blocking connection. This is not Pika nor even Python-specific - you can't block the ioloop when using `libuv`, for instance, or your own `select` loop. What Pika now provides are more obvious methods to use when you need to schedule calls to be executed in the same thread as what the ioloop runs. I realize this isn't the most user-friendly scenario and will be improving docs and examples for version `1.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum heartbeat interval when creating the `connection`.

You can see an example in the pika [documentation](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/heartbeat_and_blocked_timeouts.html).

I'd recommend against disabling the heartbeat as it might lead to hanging connections piling up on the broker. We experienced such issue in production.

Always make sure the connections have a minimum reasonable heartbeat. If the heartbeat interval needs to be long (hours for example), make sure you close the connection when the application crashes or exits. In this way you won't leave the connection open on the broker side.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that I could set "heartbeat_interval" equal to whatever value I wanted in pika.ConnectionParameters but the client heartbeat_interval could not be larger than the rabbit server's heartbeart. How would I go about increasing my rabbit server's heartbeat so I could set the client's equal to it? Would I need to create the rabbit.config file in /etc/rabbitmq and then set the value there? If so, is heartbeat_interval = 600 valid syntax for the config file? Just the one line like and follow rules here? https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Luke mentioned, heartbeats are useful but if you still want to disable them, just set heartbeat parameter to zero when creating a connection. So,

- For URL parameters: `connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters("amqp://user:pass@127.0.0.1?heartbeat=0"))`
- For Connection parameters: `connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(heartbeat=0))`